# Use Android PDF Writer but can't support chinese

Tags: android, pdf

I use the source code from [this website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/) to create a new PDF file, and it works.

The problem is that when I write Chinese in PDFWriteDemo.java : mPDFWriter.addText(70, 50, 12, "各位好"); , it can't display the characters in the PDF file normally.

Instead, it shows `???`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
   outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"ISO-8859-1");
```

to:

```
   outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"UTF-8");
```

## UPDATE

Considering that it might be the encoding issue, you'll need to follow these sequence to change the Font and Encoding:

First we found that in `PDFWriterDemo.java`, this line defines the Font and encoding:

```
mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
```

In which the `mPDFWriter` is a class that defined in `PDFWriter.java`.

As you can see in `PDFWriter.java` there's an method:

```
  public void setFont(String subType, String baseFont, String encoding) {
                    mCurrentPage.setFont(subType, baseFont, encoding);
            }
```

Where `mCurrentPage` is a class defined in `Page.java`

Here in `Page.java`

```
    public void setFont(String subType, String baseFont, String encoding) {
            IndirectObject lFont = mDocument.newIndirectObject();
            mDocument.includeIndirectObject(lFont);
            lFont.setDictionaryContent("  /Type /Font\n  /Subtype /" + subType + "\n  /BaseFont /" + baseFont + "\n  /Encoding /" + encoding + "\n");
            mPageFonts.add(lFont);
    }
```

Then you'll find that actually they didn't embed the font into the package, they just provide a font's name and with correct encoding the PDF reader will load them automatically.

Thus the solution of what I think, is to edit the `StandardFonts.java` to add the PDF standard fonts for rendering Chinese characters and a correct encoding.

Comment: it still show "%^&D(!~" /n, I thick maybe change `mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER_BOLD);` but I don't know how to add the type to this project, I had tried to copy a "mingliu.ttc" in assets file , and `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mingliu.ttc");`.

Comment: But `mPDFWriter.setFont(String, String);` should be string.

Comment: @facebook-100000072581945 please refer to my updated answer :-)